# Is there any way to access a variable from outside a function, explicitly as a variable and not via assignment to a function?

Tags: python, function, variables, python-2.7, dictionary

I'm wanting to replace keywords with values from an associated dictionary.

**file1.py**

```
import file2

file2.replacefunction('Some text','a_unique_key', string_variable1)
file2.replacefunction('Other text','another_unique_key', string_variable2)
file2.replacefunction('More text','unique_key_3', string_variable2)
```

`stringvariable1`, used in the first function call, is a local variable in `file1.py` and therefore is accessible as a parameter in the function.  It is intentionally a different variable than the one later used in that parameter position.

**file2.py**

```
import re

keywords = {
    "a_unique_key":"<b>Some text</b>",
    "another_unique_key":"<b>Other text</b>",
    "unique_key_3":"<b>More text</b>",
}

def replacefunction(str_to_replace, replacement_key, dynamic_source):
    string_variable2 = re.sub(str_to_replace, keywords[replacement_key], dynamic_source)
    return string_variable2  <-- this variable needs to be accessible
```

The replacement values in the `keywords` dictionary are more complicated than shown above, and just demonstrated like this for brevity.

The problem occurs at the second call to `replacefunction` in `file1.py` - it cannot access `stringvariable2` which is the result of the first function that is run.

I have seen that the way to access a variable produced in a function outside of that function is to do something like:

```
def helloworld()
    a = 5
    return a

mynewvariable = helloworld()

print mynewvariable

5  <-- is printed
```

But this approach won't work in this situation because the function needs to work on a string that is updated after each function call ie:

```
do this to string 2 # changes occur to string 2
do this to string 2 # changes occur to string 2
do this to string 2 # changes occur to string 2
```

I can achieve the required functionality without a function but was just trying to minimise code.

Is there any way to access a variable from outside a function, explicitly as a variable and not via assignment to a function?

Comment: I'm feeling guilty about letting you know the existence of `global` in Python. If you need to keep an internal state, well this is what objects are for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't confuse variables with *values*. The name `string_variable2` references a value, and you just return that from your function.

Where you *call* the function, you assign the returned value to a local variable, and use that  reference to pass it into the next function call:

```
string_variable2 = file2.replacefunction('Some text','a_unique_key', string_variable1)
string_variable2 = file2.replacefunction('Other text','another_unique_key', string_variable2)
file2.replacefunction('More text','unique_key_3', string_variable2)
```

Here the `replacefunction` returns *something*, that is stored in `string_variable2`, and then passed to the second call. The return value of the second function call is again stored (using the same name here), and passed to the third call. And so on.